# Testing Batch SendAll ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I am getting an error on SendAll in a unittest

This works fine...

```
 using (var service = HostContext.ResolveService<DeviceService>(authenticatedRequest))
                    {
                        service.Put(new AddConfig { ConfigName = key.KeyName, ConfigValue = key.Value, DeviceId = 0 });
                    }}
```

ServiceStack.WebServiceException: 'The operation 'AddConfig[]' does not exist for this service'

```
  //DeviceConfig
        /// <summary>
        /// To insert new Config
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns> New row Id or -1 on error</returns>
        public long Any(AddConfig request)
        {
            try
            {
                //convert request to model
                var perm = request.ConvertTo<DeviceConfig>();
                //log user
                perm.AuditUserId = UserAuth.Id;
                //insert data
                var insert = Db.Insert(perm, selectIdentity:true);
                //log inserted data
                LogInfo(typeof(DeviceConfig), perm, LogAction.Insert);
                return insert;
            }
            //on error log error and data
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e);
            }
            return -1;
        }

   [Route("/Config", "PUT")]
    public class AddConfig : IReturn<long>
    {
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }
        public string ConfigName { get; set; }
        public string ConfigValue { get; set; }
    }

public const string TestingUrl = "http://localhost:5123/";

    public void DeviceX400Test(string deviceTemaplateFile)
    {
        //Resolve auto-wired service
        WireUpService<DeviceService>();

        var requests = new[]
        {
            new AddConfig { ConfigName = "Foo" },
            new AddConfig { ConfigName = "Bar" },
            new AddConfig { ConfigName = "Baz" },
        };
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(TestingUrl);
        var deviceConfigs = client.SendAll(requests);
    }
```

MY ServiceBase for Unit Testting that builds from my .netcore appsettings.Json file

```
 public abstract class ServiceTestBase: IDisposable
    {
        //private readonly ServiceStackHost appHost;
        public BasicRequest authenticatedRequest;
        public const string TestingUrl = "http://localhost:5123/";
        public SeflHostedAppHost apphost;
        public ServiceTestBase()
        {
            var licenseKeyText = "********************************";
            Licensing.RegisterLicense(licenseKeyText);

            apphost = (SeflHostedAppHost) new SeflHostedAppHost()
                .Init()
                .Start(TestingUrl);
            //regsiter a test user
            apphost.Container.Register<IAuthSession>(c => new AuthUserSession { FirstName = "test", IsAuthenticated = true }); 
        }

        public void WireUpService<T>() where T : class
        {
            //var service = apphost.Container.Resolve<T>();  //Resolve auto-wired service
            apphost.Container.AddTransient<T>();

            authenticatedRequest = new BasicRequest
            {
                Items = {
                    [Keywords.Session] = new AuthUserSession { FirstName = "test" , UserAuthId="1", IsAuthenticated = true}
                }
            };
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            apphost.Dispose();
        }
    }

    //Create your ServiceStack AppHost with only the dependencies your tests need
    /// <summary>
    /// This class may need updates to match what is in the mvc.service apphost.cs
    /// </summary>
    public class SeflHostedAppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        public SeflHostedAppHost() : base("Customer REST Example", typeof(StartupService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            var file = Path.GetFullPath(@"../../../../cbw.services");
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(file).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddJsonFile("appsettings.LocalSQLServer.json", optional: true);
            Configuration = builder.Build();
            var sqlString = Configuration["ConnectionString"];

            RegisterServiceStack();
            //container.Register<ServiceStack.Data.IDbConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(sqlString,SqlServerDialect.Provider));
            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider));
            container.RegisterAutoWired<DatabaseInitService>();
            var service = container.Resolve<DatabaseInitService>();

            container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c =>
                new MyOrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>())
                {
                    UseDistinctRoleTables = true,
                });
            container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
            var authRepo = (OrmLiteAuthRepository)container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>();

            service.ResetDatabase();
            SessionService.ResetUsers(authRepo);
            service.InitializeTablesAndData();

            //Logging
            LogManager.LogFactory = new SerilogFactory(new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                .Destructure.UsingAttributes()
                .CreateLogger());
            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            //ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(StartupService));

            log.InfoFormat("Applicaiton Starting {Date}", DateTime.Now);
        }

        public void RegisterServiceStack()
        {
            var licenseKeyText = "****************************";
            Licensing.RegisterLicense(licenseKeyText);
        }

    }
```

My Xunit Test

```
 public class DeviceTemplateTest : ServiceTestBase
    {

        //Post Data
        //Device Sends State.XML

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("C:\\DeviceTemplate.txt")]
        public void DeviceX400Test(string deviceTemaplateFile)
        {
            //Resolve auto-wired service
            WireUpService<DeviceService>();

            var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
            IniData data = parser.ReadFile(deviceTemaplateFile);

            List<AddConfig> batch = new List<AddConfig>();
            //Iterate through all the sections
            foreach (SectionData section in data.Sections)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[" + section.SectionName + "]");

                //Iterate through all the keys in the current section
                //printing the values
                foreach (KeyData key in section.Keys)
                {
                    batch.Add(new AddConfig { ConfigName = key.KeyName, ConfigValue = key.Value, DeviceId = 0 });
                    //    using (var service = HostContext.ResolveService<DeviceService>(authenticatedRequest))
                    //{
                    //    service.Any(new AddConfig { ConfigName = key.KeyName, ConfigValue = key.Value, DeviceId = 0 });
                    //}
                }
            }

            var client = new JsonServiceClient(TestingUrl);
            var deviceConfigs = client.SendAll(batch.ToArray());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should [never return value types in Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-return-types#services-should-only-return-reference-types), your Request DTO says it returns a `DeviceConfig` Response Type DTO:

```
public class AddConfig : IReturn<DeviceConfig> { ... }
```

Which your Service should be returning instead.

I'm unclear how this can work or compile:

```
using (var service = HostContext.ResolveService<DeviceService>(authenticatedRequest))
{
    service.SendAll(new AddConfig { 
         ConfigName = key.KeyName, ConfigValue = key.Value, DeviceId = 0 
    });
}
```

Since it's calling methods on the `DeviceService` Service class directly and there is no `SendAll()` method on the `Service` class (or in your example), were you using the [Service Gateway](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway) instead?

I can't tell what the issue is from here without seeing the full source code and being able to repro the issue but it sounds like `AddConfig` is not recognized as a Service, is it appearing in the `/metadata` page? If not do you have it a class that inherits `Service`?

Otherwise if you can post a minimal repro on GitHub, I'll be able to identify the issue.

Comment: I updated the full code as well here. I'm trying to see the performance of the loading of a very large INI file.  It takes over 30 seconds doing individual posts.  Someone should find this testing code helpful. It took me sometime to get it all working and reproducing exactly what the MVC service was doing.

Comment: @SteveColeman can you please upload the minimal repro project to GitHub and send me the link?

Comment: I don't know how to send you a link in Stack. That's why I asked for an email.

Comment: @SteveColeman just paste the link to your GitHub project in the comments here.

Comment: give me some time to create another project. I cannot make this one public and I need an email to share it as its in AzureDevops GIT not Git Hub

Comment: @SteveColeman Your goal should be to create a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), remove all unnecessary code and just return an empty DTO in your Service. You shouldn't have anything confidential in your example, it should just contain the minimal code to repro the issue.

Comment: @SteveColeman can you answer my previous questions, i.e. can you confirm your Service returns a Response DTO, it's in a class that inherits the `Service` base class and that it appears in your `/metadata` page?

Comment: The load test sets up service stack based on the mvc projects Appsettings. So yes it is using and Inherts from a service. Which is why this works.  using (var service = HostContext.ResolveService<DeviceService>(authenticatedRequest))
                    {
                        service.Put(new AddConfig { ConfigName = key.KeyName, ConfigValue = key.Value, DeviceId = 0 });
                    }}  #2 i don't know if the metadata page is working. Because it will not load when I am running a unit test.

Comment: Creating a minimally viable solution for something that is trying to mimic how my main project is running... is not fast to do. Im working on it now. I addd you to the Github project. but its the full thing right now. Run the DeviceTemplateTest.cs test.. And thank you for the assistance

Comment: @SteveColeman You can't register a Service by just adding it to the IOC, ServiceStack needs to register Services itself. I'd just be passing your Services Assembly in your Integration ServiceTestBase constructor `typeof(DeviceService).Assembly` and let ServiceStack register all Services in that assembly, but if you only want to register a single service you'd need to use `IAppHost.RegisterService()` instead.

Comment: I see what you are saying about using the Service from the integration to load them all.  Isnt that what this is doing? apphost.Container.AddTransient<T>();  Loading 1 specific service for the test i am running?

Comment: Do I need to add this.. RegisterAutoWiredAs. I didn't think I did as the service actually worked until I switched to JsonServiceClient

Comment: @SteveColeman No that's just registering a dependency in the IOC (where Services are also eventually registered), but Services need to registered with ServiceStack who need to make them available as Service APIs. Using `JsonServiceClient` means you're calling Services via HTTP / i.e. integration test.

Comment: @SteveColeman so you can use ResolveService in a unit test by only registering them in an IOC, it's not actually registered as a "Service", it's just registered as a dependency which you can resolve from the IOC and use just like any other dependency but if you want to call your Service via an API endpoint it needs to be registered as a Service, typically by passing the Services Assembly in the AppHost constructor or manually using `IAppHost.RegisterService()`.

Comment: Thasnk, i had just added that and its working now. Failing wiht this now. "{\"responseStatus\":{\"errorCode\":\"InvalidCastException\",\"message\":\"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64[]' to type 'System.Object[]'.\"}}".   Aside from the error.  I'd like to change the code to load all the services. I made the ServiceTestBase extend from the the Integration project ServiceBase class. What makes it register all services?

Comment: @SteveColeman this issue was addressed in the first part of my answer, I.e. never return value types and your services need to return the same type you’ve declared in your IReturn<T> marker interface. You only need to pass in the Assembly where you’re Services are located as with any ServiceStack AppHost

Comment: I have  public long Any(AddConfig request) in the service ||  and    public class AddConfig : IReturn<long>   in the route. Is this incorrect?

Comment: You shouldn’t return value types ever and to use Auto Batching feature you must return a POCO Response Type, so you can wrap the long in a AddConfingResponse DTO.

Comment: That is clear, I will update my post with the working code and accept the answer. You provide amazing service. Thanks a lot!!